# (Not so) advanced xsl transformation of child nodes into list

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xpath, lxml

Input:

```
<root>
    <aa><aaa/><bbb/><ccc/><ddd/><eee/></aa>
    <bb><ggg/></bb>
</root>
```

Desirable output:

```
<root>
    <aa>aaa<aa>
    <aa>bbb<aa>
    <aa>ccc<aa>
    <aa>ddd<aa>
    <aa>eee<aa>
    <bb>ggg</bb>
</root>
```

I've come up with the simple xslt but it properly handles only  and doesn't create list of  tags.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- select all elements that doesn't have any child nodes (elements or text etc) -->
    <xsl:template match="//*[not(node())]">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
        <aa>aaabbbcccdddeee</aa>
        <bb>ggg</bb>
</root>
```

P.S. It is part of python script. Does it make to do such conversions using xslt in python script? Or python solution using simple xpath and python logic will work better?

Answer (score 5):

An example is not a substitute for explaining the **logic** behind the required transformation. I can think of several different ways to process your example input and arrive at the same output.

Here's a **guess** at what you want to accomplish (read the comments):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <!-- select all elements that don't have any child nodes -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[not(node())]">
        <!-- create an element with the name of the parent element -->
            <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```